# Is there a way to get wireshark to capture packets sent from/to localhost on Windows?

Tags: networking, localhost, network-monitoring, wireshark

Is there a way to get wireshark to capture packets sent from/to localhost?

When I monitor traffic going from my computer to another, or from another computer to my computer, then it works.  But from localhost to localhost does not register anything.

Comment: what platform? Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: Particularly on Windows

Comment: Please try Npcap: https://github.com/nmap/npcap, it is based on WinPcap and supports loopback traffic capturing on Windows. Npcap is a subproject of Nmap (http://nmap.org/), so please report any issues on Nmap's development list (http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a [WIKI Entry](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) about exactly this issue on the wireshark homepage.

They also mention specifics about the loopback interface regarding Windows - you could be running just into that.

> You can't capture on the local loopback address 127.0.0.1 with a Windows packet capture driver like WinPcap.

Comment: Care to elaborate why this is getting voted down?

Comment: I did not vote down but probably because even basic questions that have easily findable solutions are encouraged on this site and stackoverflow.com.  The answer is good but the tone is not.  Consider editing it and I think it will be voted up.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a native english speaker (guess I'm not the only one). I'll try to think about that in the future.

Comment: +1 for knowing and adding the link.

Comment: Upvote, good answer/link and Je comprends :)

Comment: Might want to add the quick quote "You can't capture on the local loopback address 127.0.0.1 with a Windows packet capture driver like WinPcap." from the linked page to save us the suspense...

Answer (score 6):

In Wireshark you need to choose the **lo0** interface... not En0 or En1.

Go to:

- Show the capture options
- Under "Interface" choose: lo0
- Capture and you'll see a bunch of *127.0.0.1* communication

Comment: on windows, of course, i dont believe you can do that without somehow adding a loopback interface manually.

Comment: yes, the document said: `you can capture on the loopback interface on Linux, on various BSDs including Mac OS X, and on Digital/Tru64 UNIX, and you might be able to do it on Irix and AIX, but you definitely cannot do so on Solaris, HP-UX, or Windows.`

Comment: On OSX yosemite this worked!

Comment: Yes, for most Linux.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) Application to capture loopback packets and save them in a pcap file ... and then you can open it using Wireshark

Answer (score 2):

Please try Npcap: https://github.com/nmap/npcap, it is based on WinPcap and supports loopback traffic capturing on Windows. Npcap is a subproject of Nmap (http://nmap.org/), so please report any issues on Nmap's development list (http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/).

Answer (score 1):

You want to run wireshark on the "lo" interface or on "any".

With tshark or tcpdump you can use the -i option:

```
# tcpdump -i any port http
```

(This is mostly applicable to Linux)